# Ubuntu 18.04 slows down when adjusting backlight using keyboard hot keys

Tags: keyboard, 18.04, brightness, backlight

I have a Dell inspiron 14, and when I use the keyboard hotkeys <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> to adjust the screen brightness, the system slows down and the brightness is adjusted slowly.

Sometimes it keeps adjusting in a loop, even it reaches the minimum or maximum. When it stops adjusting, the system backs to normal, but sometimes the keyboard freezes and I have to reboot.

When I was using the 16.04 version of Ubuntu, I wasn't having this problem. The problem doesn't occur when adjusting the brightness thought the top menu, and when I'm not logged in some user account.

Comment: The same happens to me using X, when I use Wayland I do not have this problem

Comment: I decided to move back to Ubuntu 16.04, everything is working fine now.

Comment: I have [reported this as a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/847001) (or actually resurrected a bug dating back to 2011). You may want to [report that you're affected too](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/847001/+affectsmetoo).